# Custom sounds for push notifications not working

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have added custom sounds for push notifications but its not working. I have followed the following steps.

> 1. Added custom sounds with extension .caf (sound is length of 8 seconds)
> 2. Added it to bundle resource
> 3. Sent the following payload from server

```
"aps" : {
        "alert" : "Hey you got a push notification.",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "ringtone.caf"
    }
```

ScreenShot of bundle resource.[image]

But its not working :( 
Is anything else required ?

Comment: do the message and badge arrive as you expect?

Comment: yes, just default tone plays instead of custom tone.

Comment: that is easy then :) you just need to move the `ringtone.caf` file into the bundle's root rather than putting into a `sounds/` sub-folder (_see more possible options [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html)_)

Comment: Tried that too. but still not working

Comment: what iOS version is your device that you're testing with?

Comment: 10.0.2, iPhone 6 plus.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the app worked for me!